# Can you escape Ravenloft with an Amulet of the Planes?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, ravenloft

Due to shenanigans of my Dungeon Master, my character managed to get an [Amulet of the Planes](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Amulet%20of%20the%20Planes#content), but accidentally teleported into Castle Ravenloft while playing the Lost Mine of Phandelver. Can my character use the Amulet to leave Barovia, or is it stuck there until I finish that campaign?

If it helps, my character is a Level 4 Warlock.

Comment: Here are some ways to escape. None may be practical for you though. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101455/how-can-i-escape-ravenloft-in-spite-of-the-dark-powers?rq=1

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### You're going to have to find another way out.

Per the *Curse of Strahd* book (emphasis added):

> #### Alterations to Magic
>
> The land of Barovia resides in its own demiplane, isolated from all other planes, including the Material Plane. *No spell — not even wish — allows one to escape from Strahd’s domain.* Astral projection, teleport, plane shift, and similar spells cast for the purpose of leaving Barovia simply fail, as do effects that banish a creature to another plane of existence. *These restrictions apply to magic* items and artifacts that have properties that transport or banish creatures to other planes.

Note that the restrictions have nothing to do with the plot of the *Curse of Strahd* adventure, but rather the nature of Barovia and the Dark Powers that control it. Barovia is a prison and a deliberately constructed (emotional) torture chamber for Strahd: He always returns, because the Dark Powers will it. He always chases and always loses his love, because the Dark Powers will it. People can only enter or leave Barovia at the will of the Dark Powers, and only as instruments serving to continually punish Strahd.

### What is a campaign?

In the original wording of your question, you made a couple of references to a "campaign". While sources like *Lost Mine of Phandelver* and *Curse of Strahd* are sometimes called "campaign sourcebooks", they are not "campaigns" themselves - they're sourcebooks *for* a campaign.

A campaign is a series of linked adventures, by the same DM (or a deliberately associated group of DMs, working together) with the same group of players. Your character hasn't transitioned from one *campaign* to another, it's changed from one *setting* (the Forgotten Realms) to another (Barovia, in Ravenloft). It's the same DM and presumably the same party, so it's all one campaign.

Comment: @T.J.L. If entry is only at the will of the Dark Powers, would it even be possible for someone to be randomly transported there?

Comment: @divibisan The Dark Powers are subject to the will of an even greater power... the DM. ;) To put it another way, while RAW for a failure with the amulet can result in a a trip to a random plane, there's no RAW to say how that plane is determined.

Comment: @divibisan Yes it would, the magic of Barovia is a one way filter. Things can go in but they can't go out thus the use of the words escape and leave rather than just generic spell effect names.

Answer (score 3):

You can only escape if the Dark Powers choose to let you go.  It has happened mostly to good characters that have fulfilled a specific purpose for the Dark Powers.  But is very, very, very rare and their is not way to make it happen.  If your character leaving would emotionally torture a dark lord, that would up the odds.  Fall in love with one of the Dark lords.  The only evil character that has ever escaped was Soth.