# Can one be Summoned Away from Ravenloft?

Tags: dnd-5e, summoning, ravenloft

Inspired by [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122790/can-you-escape-ravenloft-with-amulet-of-the-planes).

The Demiplane of Ravenloft has the "quirk" of preventing any magic that would allow one to "escape" it:

> No spell — not even wish — allows one to escape from Strahd’s domain. Astral projection, teleport, plane shift, and similar spells cast for the purpose of leaving Barovia simply fail, as do effects that banish a creature to another plane of existence. These restrictions apply to magic items and artifacts that have properties that transport or banish creatures to other planes.

So, no spell, Item, artifact, or even Deity Magic can banish a creature from Ravenloft or allow it to escape from within Ravenloft.

However, what isn't clear is whether a creature can be plucked from Ravenloft with a Summoning Spell cast from Outside of Ravenloft.

Let's say that Marcus, a Human Assassin, was transported to Ravenloft somehow. However, Marcus's employers, who are **not** happy with him, wish to interrogate him about a task he failed, and they use the **Gate** Spell.

> When you cast this spell, you can speak the name of a specific creature (a pseudonym, title, or nickname doesn't work). If that creature is on a plane other than the one you are on, the portal opens in the named creature's immediate vicinity and draws the creature through it to the nearest unoccupied space on your side of the portal. You gain no Special power over the creature, and it is free to act as the DM deems appropriate. It might leave, Attack you, or help you.

It is important to note that:

> Deities and other planar rulers can prevent portals created by this spell from opening in their presence or anywhere within their domains.

However, it seems that this rule acts more on a case-by-case, since specific portals can be prevented from opening, or they *can* be allowed to open. It also does not say that they are prevented by any general realm "rules", only by arbitration by a Deity or "Planar Ruler."

**Would it be possible to "Escape" Ravenloft by being summoned from someone outside it?**

And would it make any difference if Marcus were a PC or NPC?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion of what's meant by "summon" in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77625/discussion-between-nautarch-and-seraphswrath).

Answer (score 15):

## I'd say no

The way I read this:

> No spell — not even wish — allows one to escape from Strahd’s domain. Astral projection, teleport, plane shift, and similar spells cast for the purpose of leaving Barovia simply fail, as do effects that banish a creature to another plane of existence. These restrictions apply to magic items and artifacts that have properties that transport or banish creatures to other planes.

it isn't like an Anti-Magic field or something where the spells themselves don't get cast, it's their effect that is disallowed, so whether the spell was cast outside of Barovia or not isn't relevant.

I also read "for the purpose of leaving Barovia" to include being summoned out of it, because the person already outside trying to "summon" the person inside still have purpose of *someone* leaving Barovia, which seems within the scope of what the quoted text is trying to prevent.

That's my reading of it, anyway...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure the purpose of the spell Gate, when used as a summoning, is to have someone *leave* more than having them *brought to* the site of the summoning. I think that's a little bit of a stretch for the purpose of a spell.

Comment: @SeraphsWrath It's definitely for the purpose of having someone leave. The whole point is to make someone *leave* wherever they are so that they may *come* to where you are. Causing someone to come is just a directed way of having them leave.

Comment: @SeraphsWrath They are dependent mechanics. For a person to be brought somewhere they have to be leave somewhere. The person cannot be brought without leaving. So regardless of semantics, the casters of the spell intend for the character to leave Barovia in order for him to be brought to where they are.

Answer (score 9):

**No.** You have already pointed out that:

> Deities and other planar rulers can prevent portals created by this spell from opening in their presence or anywhere within their domains.

In past Ravenloft products, the Dark Powers have been established as having the power of over-deities within Ravenloft. (For details, please see this D&D lore question: [What are the "Dark Powers"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3084/what-are-the-dark-powers)) So no, they will block travel out.

Speaking of lore, the one-way travel into the Demiplane of Dread has been an established feature of the setting for a long time. For example, quoting from the 2e Planescape product *A Guide to the Ethereal Plane*:

> Once the mists claim a body, the poor sod's trapped within the demiplane until Ravenloft's dark powers decide to release her.

---

Here is **another way to think about this problem**: If it were possible for someone else to use the *Gate* spell to pull you out, then a carefully worded *Wish* would set you free: You could *wish* that someone cast *Gate* asking for you.

Comment: I'm not sure that the question you reference supports what you are saying. The Accepted answer claims that they may not even be entities at all, and thus not Deities, ("*Even calling them entities or an entity is a stretch.*") and the most-upvoted answer claims that the Dark Powers seem to be unable to prevent certain entities from leaving except by making them want to stay, like Isolde, who wishes to slay an Incubus whom the Dark Powers are shielding.

Comment: The accepted answer starts as: "They are some form of super-deities, or perhaps a personification of some multiversal axiom about true evil." In order to block dieties from leaving, we can argue that they must have equivalent power. Still I will try to improve the answer.

Comment: @ZwiQ "You could wish that someone cast Gate asking for you."  In the spirit of DM twisted wishes, it was an Arch Devil that summoned you xD

Comment: @SeraphsWrath: I added a direct quote from an older product.